# How to get a user's Reddit fullname?

Tags: python, api, reddit

I've been playing around the the Reddit API and I've come across this endpoint:

```
GET /api/user_data_by_account_ids
```

According the [the documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_api_user_data_by_account_ids), the query parameter for this endpoint is a comma separated list of fullnames. Reddit [defines a fullname](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#fullnames) as:

"a combination of a thing's type (e.g. Link) and its unique ID which forms a compact encoding of a globally unique ID on reddit. Fullnames start with the type prefix for the object's type, followed by the thing's unique ID in base 36. For example, t3_15bfi0."

So I'm wondering how I can determine a user's fullname? Is it listed somewhere in their profile? Or is there another endpoint in Reddit's api for getting a user's fullname?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a query to [/user/*username*/about](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_user_%7Busername%7D_about), the base-36 ID is included as the value of `id` in the `data` property of the response. Concatenate this to the value of the `kind` property in the result (this should be 't2' for any user) with an underscore in between, and you'll have their fullname.